# How to pass template variable to tag in Django?

Tags: django, templates, variables, parameters, tags

I try to pass a template variable to a tag as parameter, not sure how it works.

For instance

in template html

```
{{ question.author_id }}

{% monetize_slot question.author_id "questioner" %}
```

Here I can see the webpage show question.author_id as "2", but when I try to pass it via the tag monetize_slot, it treat it as a static string "question.author_id", not a dynamic value 2. Does anyone find a solution for this here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
def monetize_slot(author_id, str):
  return '%s: %d' % (str, author_id,)
register.simple_tag(monetize_slot)
```

Works for me..

Answer (score 1):

Try to define the template variable with {% with %}

`{% with question.author_id as author %}

    {% monetize_slot author "questioner" %}
{% endwith %}`